# Extending Spride class (Pixi.js ) in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend Pixi.Spride class in a typescript project. (i added some other properties ).
But when i instantiate my new object, i get this :

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

here is my code :

```
///<reference path="../lib/pixi.d.ts" />

    enter code here

// Module
module test {

    // Class
    export class Card extends PIXI.Sprite {
        public name: string;
        public value : number;
        
        constructor(arg : any) {
            super(arg);
        }

    }

}


and  
 for instantiation i did this : 


  var cardTexture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("img/aa.png");   
  c= new Card (cardTexture );
```

Answer (score 2):

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

This a runtime error with a clear indication that the JS *you think* is loaded by the browser is actually not there. Check your script tags (note : order is significant) or use amd / or commonjs (https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md)